# How stop google from giving too much link juice to particular URLs?

Tags: seo, google, nofollow, site-structure, link-juice

We have a product website with separate pages for product details, product images, product videos, product reviews.

We want to design a card for our products which we can use everywhere i.e. on internal website ads, cross-sell etc. Below is a sample card.

[image: bike toy product - seo]

There is a problem that we see here - this will create too many linkages to our product review, images, and videos page. The most important page for us is the product details page and we want to give maximum link juice to that page. Currently, if someone clicks on image or title i.e. "Pulsar 150 Toy Bike", we take the user to the product details page.

How can we fix this link juice distribution problem and indicate to google that product details is the most important link out of all these links?

We are apprehensive of doing no-crawl/no-follow as we are not sure if it would solve this issue.

Comment: I would make the picture and text of the card link to the product details page.

Comment: Both of these are already link to the product details page but still you have multiple links to other not so important pages like images, reviews, videos

Comment: This isn't a problem I worry about anymore.  They days of internal pagerank sculpting to this level are long gone.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Here is what Stephen is trying to explain: "In 2019 SEO, the significance of internal link juice is very minor. There are a lot of other factors you can focus on improving instead."

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular or accurate way of controlling your link juice to URLs as Google does not disclose any information as such.

However, giving "nofollow" to the URLs will stop from passing more link juice to those internal/external pages which are not important for you.

> **Notes:**
>
> Even though people recommend to do "nofollow" to stop the link juice flowing from the linked page, it is unsure whether it would decrease the significance of the linked pages.
>
> - Reason: Google values pages and ranks them based on several factors. If Google determines that the "nofollow" pages have valuable content that a lot of users are spending time on, then it might significantly rank those pages compared to similar performing pages.